# How can i execute two effects on .mousenter THIS?

Tags: jquery, css

The css effect works fine but how can i get it to use the animate effect at the same time?

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ol>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>About</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#menu').find('li').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({'text-decoration': 'underline'}).dequeue().animate({"top": "-=5px"}, "fast");
});
```

Comment: Why not do the `CSS` in `CSS`?

Comment: Why are you calling `.dequeue()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give it `position: relative;`:

```
$('#menu').find('li').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({'text-decoration': 'underline', 'position': 'relative'})
        .dequeue().animate({"top": "-=5px"}, "fast");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59hBc/)

That said, you should really do this in CSS instead of wasting resources trying to do it with jQuery:

```
#menu li {
    position: relative;
}
#menu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    top: -5px;
}
```

[CSS Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59hBc/1/)

Or, if you really do want the top position forever incrementing and never returning, use a combination, with CSS for the styling and jQuery only for the animation, as shown in my [third demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59hBc/2/).

Comment: This works good like a game for me :DD hovering over text to let it go up up in the sky. But yeah I think that was what he was asking for :]

Comment: exactly what i was looking for thank you! Woulda been cool to learn how to do it in jQuery aswell to get the kinda "slide" effect from animate. I have a floating menu on the same #div so i think that might be messing things up, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/59hBc/3/#update

Comment: @user2455414, you're just missing a closing bracket (`}`) at the end of your `if` conditional. Otherwise, it works.